# If robotframework has keyword to handle exception?

Tags: exception, robotframework, keyword

I write a keyword like this:

```
My Keyword
    [Argument]  ${param}
    Internal Keyword 1
    ...
    Internal Keyword n
    Run When Any of The Upper Keywords Failed
```

I want the keyword run as its' description, who can tell me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve this, one is to use `Run Keyword And Return Status` - it returns a boolean true/false did the wrapped keyword pass or fail. And based on that, you can run the "exception" keyword:

```
${passed 1}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Internal Keyword 1
${passed 2}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Internal Keyword 2

Run Keyword If    not ${passed 1} or not ${passed 2}    Run When Any of The Upper Keywords Failed
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have to seem it as a workaround solution, if the internal keywords are multiple, I have to use a loop to handle.

Comment: You can do it in a loop, yes; you can also group them in a keyword, and just get its status. Workaround or not, this is the exception handling capabilities of RF - its ideology is if a step fails, the case fails; thus try: except: blocks are a bit cumbersome to do.